# Does this look like a warped rotor?

Tags: brakes, hyundai

I’m no expert but these guys are saying my Front pads are grinding and Rotors are warped then they sent this picture. I didn’t hear any grinding. They said they need to replace my BRAKE ROTOR/Disc Brake Rotor PREMIUM CERAMIC BRAKE PADS and that it seized up so they now need to replace my Semi Loaded Caliper this is all for $535 ? (Parts are 375) I know cars repairs are  expensive but I cant help but feel they are acting funny when I ask questions[image][image]

Comment: And good pics, well done.

Comment: Before I provide an evaluation, I would like a picture of the back side of the rotor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blue spots like that tend to be the high spots and the gaps in between are low - this only happens when rotors are warped.

To check this you would need a dial gauge and mounted solidly (on the suspension arm for example) then rotate the rotor slowly. Any warping shows up as a reading and even a few thou can cause vibration...

And for what it is worth, I think they are correct about the pads grinding - the backing plate does look close to the rotor, new pads would have those plates away from the rotor by 3/8 or 1/2"...

Comment: @TylerNTarraBrandle You are welcome, just added a bit about the pads. Honestly I think they are telling you straight... You could ask to see the bits as they come off, good places do that with no problem... and some like to explain how and what they found.

Answer (score 1):

Those pads look done, and the rotors are completely shot; however, if you're not comfortable with the mechanics working on your cars, take it somewhere else. This is a pretty basic job, so anyone should be able to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if the blue spots are high spots or just reflection from the background. The pads are definitely past their lifespan. The rotor is also quite worn. The rings around it are from the pads being worn out or damaged. It may be turnable, as already suggested but it's hard to tell from the picture.

If the $535 is for the whole axle, than that price seems pretty good -- better than most American national chains. Judging by the price point, they seem to be shooting straight with you. If you don't need the ceramic pads get organic or semi ceramic, you'll chew through your new rotors much more slowly.

If the price is just for one wheel, find another shop. Brakes should *always* be replaced in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally turn rotors once ; the machining cost is low ( guessing for today $15 per rotor). I have ground off the outer lip myself but never had warped rotors. So I have never replaced or turned rotors in the 40 years I have had them. I understand "organic" pads do not wear rotors ; That is what is on my Nissan Murano and after 77.000 miles rotors look excellent and pad wear is minor . But I do not do any racing where ceramic pads would be needed. I agree with Mike , those pads are nearly gone.

Comment: Look into turning the rotors for sure, but check what the actual minimum allowable width is to determine if they can be turned or not.